# videoタグ内の動画のダウンロードを難しくしたい

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html5, 動画, mp4

HTML5のvideoタグで動画を閲覧できるようにした上で、閲覧したユーザーがローカルへ動画をダウンロードすることを難しくしたいと考えています。HLSやRTMPといったストリーミングプロトコルを使わずに、sourceタグにmp4動画のURLを指定する形を想定しています。
ある程度の知識と動機のあるユーザーでなければダウンロードしないよね、ぐらいのレベルでOKです。ちなみに、サーバーはrailsで構築されていますが、コードはどんな言語でもかまいません。

私の方では、以下のような方法を考え付きました。

- JavaScriptで動的にsourceタグを設定し、JavaScriptが無効化された状態での動画閲覧を制限する。その上で、JavaScriptでコンテクストメニューを無効化する。（コンテクストメニューにダウンロードオプションが表示されるためです。）
  念のため、コンテクストメニューの無効化というのは、jQueryの以下のコードで実現されるものです。

```
$('video').contextmenu(function() {
  return false;
});
```

- リファラを動画閲覧ページのURLのみに制限する。
- URLにトークンを付与し、有効期限を設定する。（一度限りのトークンを設定しようと考えたのですが、chromeなどのブラウザはリクエストにRangeヘッダーを付けて複数回リクエストを送るようになっており、断念しました。）
- 上記sourceタグ内の動画URLにどのような文字列が入るのかわかりづらくするため、ソースコードを難読化する。（chromeのデベロッパーツールなどを見れば動画のURLが出てくるので、あまり意味がないかもと思っています。）

他にダウンロードのハードルを上げるような方法はありますでしょうか。皆様のお知恵をお貸しください。

Comment: HLSやMPEG-DASHは分離した動画ファイルをHTTPで取得しているだけですが、ダメなのでしょうか。動画ファイルが頻繁に増えないのであればありだと思いますが。

Answer (score 3):

`URLにトークンを付与し、有効期限を設定する` が一般的だとは思います。

video要素を利用してMP4を再生可能とする以上、根本的にダウンロードを不可能にすることはできませんが、パッと思いつくものとして

- トークン発行のseedにUser-Agentを含め、検証時に同一User-Agentのみ許可する

  - curl/wget などによるダウンロードを制限できます

などが挙げられます。が、いずれも悪足掻きレベルと言えます。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、勝手にダウンロードされない為のサーバー側phpでのサンプルです。
　※あらかじめcookieをloginしたときなどに、セットしておく事が動作条件で
　動作確認する為のサンプルです。　制限条件などを検討、追加する必要があります。

**呼び出し**

```
<video src="hoge.php?f=sample.mp4"></video>
```

**hoge.php**

```
//setcookie("test", time(), time());//loginしたときなどに、セットしておく
//エラーは、手の内を明かしてしまうので、今回は出力しない。

$file = '';
$path = '/test/files/';

if(!isset($_COOKIE["test"])) exit;
$check = intval($_COOKIE["test"]) + (60*60*2);
if($check < time()) exit;

if(!isset($_GET['f'])){
    exit;
}else{
    if(count($_GET) > 1) exit;//余計なパラメータが来ていたら（付いていたら）終了
    $file =  $_GET['f'];
    if($file == '') exit;
}

if (file_exists($path.$file)) {//ファイルの存在確認
//今回は、最小限のヘッダーのみ出力、必要に応じて追加すること
//  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
//  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');//動画形式により適時かえること
//  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
//  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
//  header('Expires: 0');
//  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
//  header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path.$file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($path.$file);
    exit;
}

exit;
```